# Finding closest combination to current ongoing one

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm currently building a tic tac toe in vanilla javascript. However the game is 'sort of' done but I'm trying to add levels of difficulty. So basically the thing I want to do is , on every player move , to get the the closest possible winning combination based on his moves and place computer's mark into the missing winning's combinations place.

Let's say I have multidimensional array with the winning combinations

```
winningCombinations: [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 4, 8],
        [0, 3, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 4, 6],
        [2, 5, 8]
    ]
```

And the player X starts his moves. So his first move is 0, so saving player's current combination in array. So in first move the current comb is

```
currentPlayerCombintation: [0]
```

so I want to return [0,1,2], [0,4,8] and [0,3,6] from the winning combination's array.

However the player makes his second move , so he target's `4` so

```
currentPlayerCombination: [0,4]
```

and now I want to return the closest possible winning combination which is [0,4,8].

I've tried a lot of things including `every()` , `some()` , `filter()` but could not achieve the thing I want.

I've tried sort of

```
    for(let i = 0; i < this.currentPlayerCombination.length ; i++) {
            this.winningCombinations.some((arr) => {
                if(arr.includes(this.currentPlayerCombination[i])) {
                    console.log(arr);
                }
            });
        }
```

But this didnt work as expected :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare an array to an array of arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45152060/how-to-compare-an-array-to-an-array-of-arrays)

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and map the count of the matching items, get the max count and filter the array.

```js
function getWinningPositions(pos) {
    var posS = new Set(pos),
        temp = winningCombinations.map(a => [a, a.reduce((c, v) => c + posS.has(v), 0)]),
        max = Math.max(...temp.map(({ 1: c }) => c))
    return temp
        .filter(({ 1: c }) => c === max)
        .map(([a]) => a);
}

var winningCombinations = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 4, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 4, 6], [2, 5, 8]];

console.log(getWinningPositions([0]).map(a => a.join(' ')));
console.log(getWinningPositions([0, 4]).map(a => a.join(' ')));
console.log(getWinningPositions([0, 4, 5]).map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

First map the `winningCombinations` to an array of arrays whose numbers are only the numbers that have *not* been picked yet. Then, find the lowest length of those arrays, and you can identify the original `winningCombinations` which are closest to the `currentPlayerCombination`:

```js
const winningCombinations = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 4, 6],
  [2, 5, 8]
];
const currentPlayerCombination = [0, 4];

// eg: get [[1, 2], [3, 5,], [6, 7, 8], [8], ...]
const winningCombsWithoutCurrent = winningCombinations.map(arr => (
  arr.filter(num => !currentPlayerCombination.includes(num))
));
// eg: here, lowestLength should be 1, because [8] has a length of 1
const lowestLength = winningCombsWithoutCurrent.reduce((a, { length }) => Math.min(a, length), 3);

const combosWithLowestLength = winningCombsWithoutCurrent
  .reduce((a, { length }, i) => {
    if (length === lowestLength) {
      a.push(winningCombinations[i]);
    }
    return a;
  }, []);
console.log(combosWithLowestLength);
```